# Solving Convex Optimization Program with Bound Contraints

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let $0\leq L\leq 2nL<U$ and consider the convex program:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min &\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{-\frac1{2}} C_i\\
s.t. & \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \leq U\\
& a_i \leq U\\
& L\leq a_i,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $C_n>0$ are some fixed constants...

I know how to solve it using Lagrangian duality and Slater's condition if the last contraint is ommmited but how do I approach/solve this form of the problem?

I know that Slater's condition holds so its some sort of duality method but I can't resolve it..

---

So far I'm trying to setup the Lagrange dual... Clearly $\sum_{i=1}^n a_n \leq U$ implies each $a_n\leq U$ so the latter constrain is superfluous.. Therefore, the Lagrangian should be of the form:
$$
L(a_n,\lambda,\mu_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{-\frac1{2}}C_n + \lambda \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i - U\right) + \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i(L-a_i)?
$$
So by the KKT and Slater condition, we look for a zero of
$$
0 = \frac1{2}a_i^{-\frac{3}{2}}C_i + \lambda  - \mu_i
$$
which we solve (for each $i=1,\dots,n$) to obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
-\frac1{2}a_i^{-\frac{3}{2}}C_i =&  + \lambda  - \mu_i\\
\therefore a_i^{-\frac{3}{2}} =&  \frac{-\lambda  +\mu_i}{2 C_i}\\
\therefore a_i^{\star}  =& \left(2\frac{C_i}{\mu_i-\lambda}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

However, this depends on $\lambda$ and $\mu_n$ so I don't know how to proceed further..Do we then maximize for $\lambda $ and $\mu_i$?

Comment: You can easily find $a_n^*$ and get a dual problem with two variables (or n+1 variables): $\lambda, \mu_n$. What is the difficulty you have?

Comment: I think'm I'm doing something wrong since:  When trying to solve for $a_n^{\star}$ using the Lagrangian I get $a_n^{\star}=L$ which should be sub-optimal since $U>2nL$ (so I should be able to skeep shrinking the objective function by mappting $a_1^{\star}$ to $a_1^{\star} + (n-1)L$...

Comment: First of all. your original function had $a_n^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. In the Lagrangian you wrote it as $a_n^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Which one is true? I assume the original since otherwise the function is concave. Considering this is indeed the function, I get that $a_n^*=(\frac{C_n}{2(\lambda+\mu_n)})^{\frac{2}{3}}$. You could add you calculations to the question so others can verify them

Comment: @iarbel84  I get a slight variant of your epxression for $a^{\star}_i$ but even then I don't know how to proceed further....

Comment: Yeah, yours is the correct, mine had a type error. The next phase when constructing the dual problem is simply plugging $a_n^*$ into the Lagrangian. Then you get a dual function $q(\lambda,\mu_n)$ that you want to maximize. Notice that $\lambda,\mu_n\geq 0$. You might be able to solve this problem explicitly, but you might not. What was the outcome you expected?

Comment: @iarbel84 I did expect something explicit, or atleast depending only on $L,U$ and $n$ in some open-form way.... I guess this is the part I could really use some help with (aka where I get stuck)

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept of "duality". When you have an minimization problem with only equality constraints, then the "Lagrange Multipliers" method can give you an explicit solution (however not always). With multiple inequality constraints this is unlikely, and the process we described above is meant to construct a **dual problem**. The dual problem can be of favorable structure, reduced dimensionality, or provide a bound to the original primal problem. But by no means is it supposed to be a solution. It's still an optimization problem, but it resides in the dual space

Comment: Ah I didn't realize, but by looking at the dual problem (if there is no duality gap) then we can still find the optimal value of the primal?  If so would we get that by plugging the $a_i^{\star}$ into the Lagrangian?

Comment: Strong duality means that the optimal value of both problem is identical. If you have a solution vector of the dual you can extract a primal solution. But first you need to solve the dual somehow :) I suggest you post the dual problem $\max_{\lambda\geq 0, \mu_n\geq 0} q(\lambda, \mu_n)$ in accordance with the process I described above. Maybe it can be explicitly solved. If not, maybe it's easier to solve it using an iterative scheme. In general though, the problem you posted is not hard to solve, using first order methods or interior point methods for optimization